# How to return record from an Oracle function with JOIN query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I can easily create function that returns a myTable%ROWTYPE but what if my query (in the function) as another column from ANOTHER table?

```
t1_rec t1%ROWTYPE;
```

Do I append new fields to the major table or what?

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t2.col4...
```

**Question**:

How do I efficiently create a record type to contain the result set of the above query?

What I want is something like

```
t1_rec t1%ROWTYPE (plus another column for t2.col4%TYPE inside t1_rec)
```

Sorry for the vague question at first.

Comment: Please elaborate a little more about what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a strongly typed cursor and its rowtype:

```
-- example data
create table t1(pk number not null primary key, val varchar2(30));
create table t2(
  pk number not null primary key, 
  t1_fk references t1(pk), 
  val varchar2(30));

insert into t1(pk, val) values(1, 'value1');
insert into t2(pk, t1_fk, val) values(1, 1, 'value2a');
insert into t2(pk, t1_fk, val) values(2, 1, 'value2b');

declare
  cursor cur is 
  select t1.*, t2.val as t2_val 
  from t1
  join t2 on t1.pk = t2.t1_fk;

  function get_data(arg in pls_integer) return cur%rowtype is
      l_result cur%rowtype;
    begin
      select t1.*, t2.val as t2_val 
        into l_result 
        from t1 
        join t2 on t1.pk = t2.t1_fk
        where t2.pk = arg;
      return l_result;
    end;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(get_data(2).t2_val);
end;
```

**UPDATE**: you can easily wrap the cursor and function inside a PL/SQL package:

```
create or replace package pkg_get_data as 

  cursor cur is 
  select t1.*, t2.val as t2_val 
  from t1
  join t2 on t1.pk = t2.t1_fk;

  function get_data(arg in pls_integer) return cur%rowtype;
end;
```

(package body omitted)

Comment: Thanks for this answer sir, definitely gave me ideas (and more keywords to search in google later) but what if I want my record types to be accesssible package-wide?

Comment: You can declare the cursor inside the package.

Comment: Thanks for this answer sir I find it very disturbing seeing queries like that in package headers -_- or is this just something those unfamiliar with oracle feel.

Comment: For example my t1 contains around 10 columns and I am to select only 2 for those while t2 contains around 10 columnas as well and I am to select only 1 (3 columns in total to select in query), Is it worth to to define a record? and manually defining each field of the record for every selected column in the query?

Comment: I usually use procedures with a sys_recursor in/out parameter instead of a function. The procedure then performs a OPEN p_cur FOR <query> - no need to define any custom types.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33545/discussion-between-kampai-and-frank-schmitt)